# get a reference to this.objectController attribute from an Ember.TextField class

Tags: ember.js

In my app I have a generic text field of  type `Em.TextField`:

```
App.DetailTextField = Em.TextField.extend({   
    attributeBindings: ['required', 'readonly', 'name']
});
```

In my template I use the DetailTextField  to show data, to specify an attribute, and to show it in the class of either 'editing' or 'viewing':

```
{{view App.DetailTextField viewName="tbSurname" placeholder="surname"
valueBinding="surname" required="required" classNameBindings="isEditing:editing:viewing" readonlyBinding='getReadOnlyState'}}
```

This works fine but I have several of these fields, all of which have the same part: `classNameBindings="isEditing:editing:viewing" readonlyBinding='getReadOnlyState'`. `isEditing` and `getReadOnlyState` are retrieved from the current objectController of the template view.

Is there a way to put the `classNameBindings` and `readonlyBinding` into the `DetailTextField` class definition, so that it does not need to be explicitely typed into every instance of the DetailTextField view? That is, can DetailTextField get the current context - e.g:

```
App.DetailTextField = Em.TextField.extend({

    attributeBindings: ['required', 'readonly', 'name'],
    classNameBindings: "this.view.get('isEditing'):editing:viewing"
```

});

I could make `isEditing` a function within the class definition that retrieved the value from the controller, but I still have the same problem in that I would not know how to reference the activeController / this.controller.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

To access controller from your view, simply

```
mycontroller = this.get('controller');
```

Btw, I prefer to put isEditing attribute in my model, so I don't have to extend views.

```
App.MyModel.reopen({
    isEditing: false
});
```

So I can loop each of them...

```
{{#each model}}
    {{#if isEditing}}
        {{view Em.TextField valueBinding="yourvaluebindinghere"}}
        <button {{action 'update' this}}>Update</button>
    {{else}}
        {{yourvaluebindinghere}}
        <button {{action 'edit' this}}>Edit</button>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

And put the actions in my controller:

```
App.MyController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        edit: function(model) {
            model.set('isEditing', true);
        },

        update: function(model) {
            model.save();
            model.set('isEditing', false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. First, I am still unsure how to use `this.get('controller')` in my Em.TextField extended class to replace the classNameBindings statement in my template. I could use a #if helper but my aim is to reduce lines in the template and avoid having to change several {{view Em.TextField..}} if I change the way my classNameBingings works.

Comment: Second, I have your suggestion for isEditing inside a ObjectController, which wraps the model for the current #each. I like that the model is kept purely for persistant data. It allows the same coding as your example. Is there other advantages?

Comment: The benefits of placing isEditing attribute inside a model allows you to use #each in an ArrayController. It's just a preference.